# vega visualization tool data limitations

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vega

How much data (how many records) can vega handle without any noticeable delay in response to signals created for interactivity.

I couldn't use the URL because of cross origin problems, but created JSON for 60000 records and pasted it in my vega specifications.

I have 4 signals in total - **3** for single value filtering on mouseclick and **1** for range filtering using click and drag select. The dashboard created responds to each signal trigger after nearly 30 seconds.

So I wanted to know the maximum amount of data that can be used in vega and also any alternatives like interfacing vega with something to speed up the process? Any help will be appreciated.